# Gulp sass and browsersync reloading browser instead of injecting css

Tags: javascript, css, gulp, gulp-sass, gulp-browser-sync

I am using the latest gulp sass and browsersync.  Upon editing and saving a scss file, it compiles and I see  the "injecting styles.css" **BUT** the browser also reloads.

Not sure when this changes, but it used to just inject the new css file without a reload.

My task:

```
var sassFiles = './app/assets/sass/**/*.{scss,sass}';
var cssFiles = './app/assets/css';
var cssBuildFiles = './build/assets/css';

var sassOptions = {
  errLogToConsole: true,
  outputStyle: 'compact'
};

var autoprefixerOptions = {
  browsers: ['last 2 versions']
};


  gulp.task('sass', function () {
  return gulp
    .src(sassFiles)
    .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
    .pipe(sass(sassOptions).on('error', sass.logError))
    .pipe(autoprefixer(autoprefixerOptions))
    .pipe(sourcemaps.write('./'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(cssFiles))
    .pipe(browserSync.stream());
});
```

Once, I used a filter to pipe only the css file to browsersync, since someone told me the map file was triggering a reload.  Not sure if I really need to do that, as most online examples are like what I have here...

Comment: In your sass function `.pipe(browserSync.stream());` is what's setting the page to reload. You can change the options here https://www.browsersync.io/docs/gulp#gulp-manual-reload

Comment: well, i do want it to inject the new css.  That's what "Stream" is supposed to do, without a full reload.

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure you've set `injectChanges` to `true` in your initialization options.

   ```
   browserSync.init({
       proxy:"http://localhost:8888",
       injectChanges: true
   });
   ```
2. Try passing a filter to the stream method to restrict which changes are injected

`browserSync.stream({match: "**/*.css"})`